# D3 transition not working

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I have the following SVG element:

```
<svg id='svgTest' xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
  <g id="test">
    <rect height="20" width="50" fill="blue"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```

I want to add a transition for the blue rectangle.  I tried with the following code with D3:

```
var rect = d3.select("#test");
rect.transition().duration(5000).attr('height',200);
```

But it doesn't seem to do anything.  What's wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to select the 'rect' element. Try this:

```
var rect = d3.select("#test rect");

rect.transition().duration(5000).attr('height',200);
```

If you want to update multiple elements, use d3.selectAll().

Comment: If I want to move the whole group, can I just select the group instead?

Comment: No - to modify g elements you have to apply transforms.

Comment: Is there a way to loop through all the elements within a group so I can apply transforms on them?